# Changing numpy array size on the fly

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy array that starts out empty and over the course of a loop is supposed to receive a number of entries, though I don't know how many entries there will be prior to execution.

I've tried different things to varying success and currently my code looks something like this:

```
pi = np.empty((0))

for...
    if...
        np.concatenate([pi, np.array([0])]) # supposed to ad a new column with entry '0'
```

However `print(pi)` returns `[]`

I suspect that my limited knowledge of numpy might be to blame here, though I can't spot any obvious errors.

Also since I need to work with the values in the array within the loop, I unfortunately can't wait with its initialization until the loop

Comment: You have to assign the result of `np.concatenate` to `pi`.

Comment: Don't try to imitate list `[]` and `append` with arrays!  As you found it is error prone, and also slow.

Comment: Keepi in that `concatenate` makes a new array, copying values to the input arrays.  As it grows the amount of copying grows.  List `append` operates in-place, just adding a reference to the list.  It is simpler and faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not assigning the new array to pi.

```
pi = np.empty((0))

for...
    if...
        pi = np.concatenate([pi, np.array([0])])
```